# Java Gradle with Selenium webdriver error at Jar Runtime

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gradle, dependencies

In a basic Gradle project, I found an issue or bug where when I use `implementation` instead of `compile` it doesn't run within a jar. My main class has two imports, `import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;` and `import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;` But it doesn't seem to like it when I use implementation.

```
implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.141.59'
```

```
compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.141.59'
```

When I use `implementation` I get,

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class Main.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
```

But when I use `compile` it works and loads just fine. It is the only thing I changed, I thought both statements meant the same thing but for anyone who had a similar issue, there you go. (I know compile is deprecated but it works)

Answer (score 0):

Just try replacing `implementation` with `compile`